# convert integer to array of object.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object, underscore.js

```
var items = [
          { "id": 1, "label": "Item1" },
          { "id": 2, "label": "Item2" },
          { "id": 3, "label": "Item3" }
    ];
```

I have this array of objects named 'items'. I get itemselected = 3 from the database.

I need to convert this 3 into the following form.

```
0:Object
  id:3
  label:"Item3"
```

Similarly, if i have a value 2 coming from the database, i should convert it to

```
 0:Object
  id:2
  label:"Item2"
```

Can anyone please let me hint of how to get it solved. i am not here to get the answer. These questions are quite tricky for me and i always fail to get the logic right. Any advice on how to master this conversions will be of great help. thanks.

Comment: Is this JSON? If so, can't you use JSON.parse first then just use the parsed objects?

Comment: Not sure I get it, wouldn't this be as easy as `items[value - 1]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `underscore.js`, this should be very easy:

```
var selectedObject = _.findWhere(items, {id: itemselected});
```

Using ECMA6, you can achieve the same using `.find` method on arrays:

```
let selectedObject = items.find(el => el.id === itemselected);
```

With ECMA5, you can use `filter` method of arrays. Be careful that filter returns undefined if no element has been found:

```
var selectedObject = items.filter(function(el) { return el.id === itemselected});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your question: «***convert integer to array of object***». You can use **JavaScript** [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example).

> The `filter()` method **creates a new array** with all elements that
>   pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Something like this:

```js
var items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Item1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Item2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "Item3"
  }
];
var value = 2;
var result = items.filter(function(x) {
  return x.id === value;
});
console.log(result); // Prints an Array of object.
```

[image: Array of object]

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery $.map function as below

```
$.map(item, function( n, i ) { if(n["id"] == 3) return ( n );});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var obj = {} ; 
items = [
      { "id": 1, "label": "Item1" },
      { "id": 2, "label": "Item2" },
      { "id": 3, "label": "Item3" }
];
items.map(function(n) { obj[n.id] = n });
```